# Which version is deployed if Jenkins Build failed?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, repository

I heard about Jenkins. What happens if Jenkins artifact building is failed?

For example, there are many artifacts like db, skins and web. All these artifacts will build every day and deployed. Which version of my webpage will be online, if building fails? The last successfully built version?

Thanks.

Comment: We need more information on what it is you're trying to do. Typically, in the scenario you're talking about, Jenkins runs a Maven build on your project, and then takes the build artifact and does something with it (for example, you can use a Jenkins plug-in to drop it on your deployment box). If the build fails for any particular reason, then your site will not get updated.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to know.